# Get order of values in common between many lists of names?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I have 800 lists with an order of names. The lists can range anywhere from 0 to 1000 items long

Ex:

```
 [Bob, Sam, Mike, John, Adams]
 [Bob, Washington, John, Adams]
 [Remy, Alex]
 [Sanders, Jeffrey, Bob]
```

The idea is to find out the general order of names.

So were I given these four, the 'known' longest order would be:

```
 [Sanders, Jeffrey, Bob, Sam, Mike, John, Adams.]
```

Everything else I basically can't use as I can't place them

That's already difficult as is with 800 lists, as maybe something can't be placed currently, but after incorporating a few hundred lists, maybe that thing I 'left aside' can now be incorporated, so I would have to go back.

To make things worse, there is a big caveat, and this kinda messes up some methods. That if in the rare case the names happened at the 'exact same time', then their order might be messed up in another list.

For example:

If Remy & Alex showed up at the exact same time, it might be

```
 [Alex, Remy, Samuel]
```

in one list, and

```
 [Ron, Bob, Remy, Alex]
```

in another list. Where Alex and Remy are switched. So we can't use them. It's rare, but it can happen with multiple together.

Any ideas are appreciated it, I'm trying to figure it out. Seems like a mix of sorting and regression, but I can't quite place my thumb on it.

Thanks

Comment: construct a tree graph out of it, then use the longest root to leaf path in the largest component?

Comment: That could work. And in the case of loops (because of caveat) I find a way to remove them so they're not considered? Which python library would you say is best for this?

Comment: Edit, got it loaded on networkx, not use how to have it ignore the caveat case.

Comment: Edit, I can get the cycles, I'll remove them from original df and see what happens. Have to recursively re-remove cycles as new ones get introduced.

Comment: Edit again, I just end up with a lot of cycles I'm not sure how I can deal with without butchering it in NX

Comment: It might help to pose a problem a bit differently, perhaps as an optimization problem. E.g. you might want to find such an order of names that minimizes the number of "contradictions" in the "training set".

Comment: The graph approach requires certain degree of regularity in the data. It is relatively easy to deal with cases like `[A, B]; [B, A]`, but if there are triplets `[A, B, C]; [C, A, B]` or longer cycles it will get nasty. Without having the data or at least some background info it is hard to make a more informed guess how to deal with this problem.